# Laravel Implementing Social Auth for API (via mobile app) with Socialite & jwt

Tags: laravel, flutter, api, jwt

While I was developing an API for a mobile app, I faced the issue of how I could implement a social authentication (Facebook, Google) between our mobile app and our API.

Laravel Implementing Social Auth for API (via mobile app) with Socialite & jwt

Comment: In a simple google search you can find multiples examples on how accomplish that, for example: https://dev.to/philipdroubi/laravel-9-api-authentication-via-sanctum-socialite-and-test-on-postman-2iki#:~:text=In%20this%20post%2C%20I%20will%20show%20you%20how,test%20Or%20by%20this%20command%3A%20laravel%20new%20test

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.